# How can I get a variable name to be read in a writeBin command in R?

Tags: r, variables

I am having trouble getting writeBin to cooperate.  I'm trying to get it to accept the value of a variable as one of its arguments:

The following works:

```
writeBin(ACTUAL.VARIABLE, paste0(RSTATDATA,".raw"),size = 4, endian = .Platform$endian)
```

But what I want to do is replace "ACTUAL.VARIABLE" (which is a vector of stats that I have created in R already), with a variable name whose contents is the name "ACTUAL.VARIABLE".

What I'm trying to do is create a function that allows the user to enter a particular variable name (using readline), which my function will then write out as a bin file.  Something like:

```
RSTATDATA<-readline("enter the name of the R variable that has your stats (must be a vector): ")
writeBin(RSTATDATA, paste0(RSTATDATA,".raw"),size = 4, endian = .Platform$endian)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work (only writes 41 bytes out, which is much smaller than the vector I'm trying to write).  I'm thinking there is some syntax I'm missing here, because I don't understand why putting the actual R object name works, but putting a variable containing the name of the R object does not.

Thanks for any suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to undesrtand your question , but I think you need to use `get`, try this:

```
  writeBin(get(RSTATDATA), paste0(RSTATDATA,".raw"),
           size = 4, endian = .Platform$endian)
```

So your function must look like this :

```
  my.writeBin <- function(RSTATDATA){
    filename <- paste0(RSTATDATA,".raw")
    zz <- file(filename, "wb")
    writeBin(get(RSTATDATA), zz)
    close(zz)
  }
```